# Open many links at once in Safari

Tags: safari, web-browsing, tabs

Can several links be opened at once in Safari?
Imagine you are on a page with a lot of links:

[image]

Would it be possible to select all the links and open them all in one single Command-click? As such:

[image]

I am often finding myself Command-clicking links for dozens of minutes a day, and wishing I could open more links all at once. Surely I'm not the only person in this situation!

Comment: For anyone who is open to using another browser, there are many extensions for firefox and chrome that do this. For Chrome I'd recommend [Linkclump](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj) and for Firefox [Multi Links Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-links-plus/)

Comment: Thank you for this comment. [Sleipnir](http://www.sleipnirbrowser.com) has a function [that does this natively](http://imgur.com/a/bI2fy).

Comment: Also, I'm not "against" using, say, Chrome, but the direct right-click option to "save image to downloads" in Safari is a huge time gain (and other features)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do something close - it involves adding a bookmarklet to Safari and selecting that once you're on the page.

However, this will either open only the hyperlinks you've selected (i.e. highlighted) on the page or it will open **all** hyperlinks found on the page if you haven't highlighted any. In other words, it doesn't work in the <kbd>Command</kbd> + click manner you want.

If you're interested, here's the process to set this up:

1. Visit any page using Safari
2. Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to add a bookmark to the page you just visited
3. In the highlighted field that appears in the window, change the text to something like *Open all hyperlinks*
4. Press <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to edit bookmarks
5. Find the bookmark you just added and right-click on it
6. Select Edit Address... from the context menu
7. This should highlight the URL. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove it
8. Now paste the following code where the URL was previously:

`javascript:(function(){var n_to_open,dl,dll,i; function linkIsSafe(u) { if (u.substr(0,7)=='mailto:') return false; if (u.substr(0,11)=='javascript:') return false; return true; } n_to_open = 0; dl = document.links; dll = dl.length; if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().containsNode) { /* mozilla */ for(i=0; i<dll; ++i) { if (window.getSelection().containsNode(dl[i], true) && linkIsSafe(dl[i].href)) ++n_to_open; } if (n_to_open && confirm('Open ' + n_to_open + ' selected links in new windows?')) { for(i=0; i<dll; ++i) if (window.getSelection().containsNode(dl[i], true) && linkIsSafe(dl[i].href)) window.open(dl[i].href); } } /* /mozilla */ if (!n_to_open) { /*ie, or mozilla with no links selected: this section matches open_all_links, except for the alert text */ for(i = 0; i < dll; ++i) { if (linkIsSafe(dl[i].href)) ++n_to_open; } if (!n_to_open) alert ('no links'); else { if (confirm('No links selected. Open ' + n_to_open + ' links in new windows?')) for (i = 0; i < dll; ++i) if (linkIsSafe(dl[i].href)) window.open(dl[i].href); } } })();`

9. Press <kbd>Return</kbd> to accept the code

To make this work, open any page in Safari and then select the bookmarklet. One of the following things will happen:

- if you haven't highlighted any hyperlinks on the page, the code will proceed to open all hyperlinks in a separate tab
- if you've highlighted *x* number of hyperlinks, then the code will proceed to open those selected hyperlinks in separate tabs

**IMPORTANT:** If this doesn't work for you, ensure that you have Javascript enabled. You can do this via Safari > Preferences > Security.

**One more thing** - I have tried many times to get the above javascript to work as a Service in Safari (thinking that would be better than the *bookmark* approach), but have never been able to get it to work. On the off-chance you do, please share how. :)

Comment: The most recent (at least *a* recent) Safari upgrade appears to have broken this ... the script is only opening the first link. Any suggestions on a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://greasyfork.org/scripts/471560 if you can use Tampermonkey in Safari, it's a reimplement of [Linkclump](https://github.com/benblack86/linkclump), but in userscript

You can install Tampermonkey or Stay by search the name in MacOS app store

Comment: This might be more useful with some explanations on how to get/install Tampermonkey for Safari.